# optimal way to remove unwanted js and css files from page

Tags: 6, theming, javascript, ubercart

I use drupal 6 and ubercart2. Loading of cart and checkout page takes a while so I am thinking about removing any js and css files which are not used on specific pages.
What would be the ideal way to do it? I know about js agregation but want to try the first approach.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a side note, but the combination of JS/CSS aggregation with proper cache headers (or origin pull CDN) can really make a site fly. Look at the .htaccess fro HTML5 Boilerplate for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

The [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg/) module can do this fairly easily. Syntax for this is different between 6.x & 7.x. This is the hook syntax for 6.x. Works very similar to [hook_css_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) & [hook_js_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) in Drupal 7. Using these hooks is how to do it in D7 BTW.

```
hook_advagg_css_pre_alter(&$css, $preprocess_css, $public_downloads) {
  // Remove css files.
}
hook_advagg_js_pre_alter(&$js, $preprocess_js, $public_downloads) {
  // Remove js files.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FOAD](http://drupal.org/node/1536790) technique to get rid of stylesheets and scripts. It happens in your own theme.

You can take an alternate route and use stuff like [Stylestripper](http://drupal.org/project/stylestripper) module or [Mothership](http://drupal.org/project/mothership) base theme.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your question 'optimal way to remove unwanted js and css files from page', hope this approach works ::

1) Include your js & css files only under appropriate hook as per applicable

2) Use syntax like -

drupal_add_js (drupal_get_path ('module', 'module_name') . '/js/js_file_name.js' 
);
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/css/css_file_name.css');

3) You can make use of syntax like this to set some settings variable & check in your js file before invoking your event inside the behavior

In module file ::

drupal_add_js (array ('module_name' => array ('variable_name' => some_value)), 'setting' );

In js file ::

```
   Drupal.behaviors.testName = {
     attach: function (context, settings) {
       if(typeof Drupal.settings.module_name != 'undefined' 
    && 
    Drupal.settings.module_name.variable_name == some_value){
      // Do SOMETHING
       }
     }
  };
```

4) If your code already included js & css files at places which could be done a better way, then you need to make the code changes accordingly. For example,

If we could include the js & css files in hook_node_view (based on D7 standard, say), then we should not include it from hook_init.

Hope it helps